# Closing out of an Excel Workbook

Tags: python, winapi

I am trying to run a code to close out of a workbook. I have been running this code for weeks, but today it won't work. So this is my code. I know the first four letters of my file, but that's it. Sometimes it's XXXX1_(Random letters). So I want to close all workbooks that start with XXXX.

The top code is what was working for a month. The bottom code is what I tried to use to see my active workbooks, which led to a Syntax error. Do you have any idea how to modify the code for it to close out of the active workbooks with XXXX? Do you know why the code stopped working. Thank you very much for your time.

```
 try:
        import win32com.client as win32
        excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
        for wb in excel.Workbooks:
            if wb.Name[:4] == 'xxxx':
                print("WB:",wb.Name,'Closed ')
                wb.Close()


try:
    import win32com.client as win32
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    for wb in excel.Workbooks:
        print(wb.Name)
```

Comment: You need to add `excel` and `win32com` tag.

Comment: I thought that's what I was doing when I defined the excel? Can you elaborate further?